# Are the higher octave notes required in the chords for Hilda's theme song?

Tags: guitar, piano, chords, arranging, octave

I'm trying to teach myself the theme song for the Netflix original show, Hilda:

With that, I used [Chordify](https://chordify.net/chords/hilda-opening-theme-extended-arigatoki) to confirm and deny my suspicions for the chords involved:

[image: Screenshot of the chords from Chordify.]

Additionally, I browsed for some resources and found a video demonstrating a "piano cover" of the song:

While this follows the chord progression Chordify gave, and also supplies me with the individual notes for the melody (hooray for less guess work), it contains additional notes in the chords and the octave range seems too wide. For example, the first chord presented is an A minor chord:

> A2 E3 A3 A5 C6 E6

However, not only does it contain an extra A note, the higher notes are two octaves higher than a natural A minor on the guitar which, from my understanding has a range of A2 to E4:

> A2 E3 A3 C4 E4

As demonstrated by this mapping:

[image: Screenshot of a mapping between a guitar's fretboard and a piano's keys.]

Are the higher octave notes presented with the chords in the "piano cover" required to accurately cover Hilda's theme song on guitar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high piano chords can be left out. Even better, they would be played in a lower octave — the same as the melody. This can actually be done somewhat more easily on guitar in this case. Moving the chords lower to accommodate the range of the guitar would actually make for a more accurate presentation of the original, since the melody and chords are in about the same range.

Anytime one makes an arrangement of a song, especially on a different instrument, compromises have to be made: notes omitted, octaves changed, the whole piece transposed, parts left out or adapted (say, drums, in this case), etc.

Creating an "accurate cover" comes down to presenting enough of the most recognizable aspects of the music that the listener (even if just yourself) hears something close enough to what they identify with.

Comment: I was working on an answer saying almost the same thing: an arrangement keeps what makes the work recognizable, while adapting other things to suit the instrument. If you're planning to strum, the chord voicing can be even more flexible; you might want to do fingerstyle to mimic the arpeggiated pattern of the original, in which case you might have to play around with the chord voicings to get the pattern you want.